# android circle shape is not resizing correctly in android launcher

Tags: java, android

hello I am working on a android launcher and I want it to where there is a circle shape behind every app icon I am referencing the shape via the java code NOT XML! So I used this code as my shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke  android:color="#ccc" android:width="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <size android:width="100dp" android:height="100dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and here's my class that makes the app irons for the launcher:

```
package appname.widget;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.ColorInt;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.HapticFeedbackConstants;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import appname.R;
import appname.util.AppManager;
import appname.util.DragAction;
import appname.util.GoodDragShadowBuilder;
import appname.util.LauncherSettings;
import appname.util.Tool;

import static android.R.attr.button;
import static android.R.attr.width;
import static com.bennyv5.materialpreffragment.R.attr.height;

/**
 * Created by BennyKok on 10/23/2016.
 */

public class AppItemView extends View implements Drawable.Callback{

    public Drawable getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }


    public void setIcon(Drawable icon, boolean isStatic) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.icon.setCallback(this);





    }

    @Override
    public void refreshDrawableState() {
        invalidateDrawable(icon);
        super.refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        invalidate();
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public float getIconSize() {
        return iconSize;
    }

    public void setIconSize(float iconSize) {
        this.iconSize = iconSize;
    }

    private float iconSize;

    private Drawable icon;
    private String label;

    public boolean isShortcut;

    public  Paint textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private Rect mTextBound = new Rect();

    private boolean noLabel,vibrateWhenLongPress;

    private float labelHeight;



    public AppItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public AppItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        labelHeight = Tool.convertDpToPixel(14,getContext());

        textPaint.setTextSize(sp2px(getContext(),14));
        textPaint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    }

    public static int sp2px(Context context, float spValue) {
        final float fontScale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
        return (int) (spValue * fontScale + 0.5f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (label != null && !noLabel){
            textPaint.getTextBounds(label,0,label.length(),mTextBound);
        }

        //The height should be the same as they have the same text size.
        float mHeight = iconSize + (noLabel? 0 : labelHeight);
        float heightPadding = (getHeight() - mHeight)/2f;

        if (label != null && !noLabel) {
            float x = (getWidth()-mTextBound.width())/2f;
            if (x < 0)
                x = 0;
            canvas.drawText(label,x, getHeight() - heightPadding, textPaint);
        }

        if (icon != null){
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate((getWidth()-iconSize)/2,heightPadding);
            icon.setBounds(0,0,(int)iconSize,(int)iconSize);
            icon.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }



    public static class Builder{
        AppItemView view;

        public Builder(Context context){
            view = new AppItemView(context);

            float iconSize = Tool.convertDpToPixel(LauncherSettings.getInstance(view.getContext()).generalSettings.iconSize, view.getContext());
            view.setIconSize(iconSize);


        }

        public AppItemView getView(){
            return view;
        }

        public Builder setAppItem(AppManager.App app){
            view.setIcon(app.icon,true);
            view.setLabel(app.appName);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iconbackbg);
            view.setScaleX(0.75f); // <- resized by scaling
            view.setScaleY(0.75f);


            return this;
        }

        public Builder withOnClickLaunchApp(final AppManager.App app){
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Tool.createScaleInScaleOutAnim(view, new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Tool.startApp(view.getContext(), app);

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withOnLongClickDrag(final AppManager.App app,final DragAction.Action action,@Nullable final OnLongClickListener eventAction){
            withOnLongClickDrag(Desktop.Item.newAppItem(app),action,eventAction);
            view.setScaleX(0.75f); // <- resized by scaling
            view.setScaleY(0.75f);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withOnLongClickDrag(final Desktop.Item item, final DragAction.Action action, @Nullable final OnLongClickListener eventAction){

            view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    if (view.vibrateWhenLongPress)
                        v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.putExtra("mDragData", item);
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newIntent("mDragIntent", i);
                    v.startDrag(data, new GoodDragShadowBuilder(v), new DragAction(action), 0);
                    if (eventAction != null)
                        eventAction.onLongClick(v);
                    return true;

                }
            });
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withOnTouchGetPosition(){
            view.setOnTouchListener(Tool.getItemOnTouchListener());
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setTextColor(@ColorInt int color){
            view.textPaint.setColor(color);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setNoLabel(){
            view.noLabel = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder vibrateWhenLongPress(){
            view.vibrateWhenLongPress = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setShortcutItem(final Intent intent){
            view.isShortcut = true;
            view.setScaleX(0.75f); // <- resized by scaling
            view.setScaleY(0.75f);
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Tool.createScaleInScaleOutAnim(view, new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);



                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            view.setIcon(Tool.getIconFromID(view.getContext(),intent.getStringExtra("shortCutIconID")),true);
            view.setLabel(intent.getStringExtra("shortCutName"));

            return this;

        }
    }


}
```

EDIT I Tried suggestion but the circle does not show up at all heres the Updated On draw method:

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        //Load your oval shape

        Drawable background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconbackbg, getContext().getTheme());

//create a LayerDrawable that combines the oval shape with the icon
        Drawable[] layers = {background, icon};



        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

//set the gravity of both drawables to center
        layerDrawable.setLayerGravity(0, Gravity.CENTER);
        layerDrawable.setLayerGravity(1, Gravity.CENTER);
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (label != null && !noLabel){
            textPaint.getTextBounds(label,0,label.length(),mTextBound);
        }

        //The height should be the same as they have the same text size.
        float mHeight = iconSize + (noLabel? 0 : labelHeight);
        float heightPadding = (getHeight() - mHeight)/2f;

        if (label != null && !noLabel) {
            float x = (getWidth()-mTextBound.width())/2f;
            if (x < 0)
                x = 0;
            canvas.drawText(label,x, getHeight() - heightPadding, textPaint);
        }

        if (layerDrawable != null){
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate((getWidth()-iconSize)/2,heightPadding);
            layerDrawable.setLayerWidth(1, (int) iconSize);
            layerDrawable.setLayerHeight(1, (int) iconSize);
            layerDrawable.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }

        if (icon != null){
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate((getWidth()-iconSize)/2,heightPadding);
            icon.setBounds(0,0,(int)iconSize,(int)iconSize);
            icon.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }
```

the circle shape is showing up its just resized very funky heres a screenshot of what it looks link on a nexus 7 tablet:
[image]

any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess `R.drawable.iconbackbg` is the reference for the ShapeDrawable?

If so, setting it as the background of your View makes it draw with the View's bounds. So if your View's width and height are not equal, it will draw an oval as your background instead of a circle (hence the name of the shape "oval").

If you want to draw it as a circle, you need to override the drawables bounds in some way. That's not possible when using platform drawables and setting them as the background of a view, as the view will override the drawables bounds during draw().

A possible solution would be to wrap the app's icon together with your oval ShapeDrawable in a LayerDrawable (A LayerDrawable is basically a list of drawables that get drawn on top of each other):

```
private void init(){
    //... do your initilizations
    //Load your oval shape 
    background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconbackbg, getContext().getTheme());
}

public void setIcon(Drawable icon){
    //... set the icon, be sure to remove callbacks to the previously set icon!

    //create a LayerDrawable that combines the oval shape with the icon
    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(background, icon);

    //set the gravity of both drawables to center
    layerDrawable.setLayerGravity(0, Gravity.CENTER);
    layerDrawable.setLayerGravity(1, Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

and then in your onDraw() do:

```
if (layerDrawable != null){
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate((getWidth()-iconSize)/2,heightPadding);
    layerDrawable.setLayerWidth(1, (int) iconSize);
    layerDrawable.setLayerHeight(1, (int) iconSize);
    layerDrawable.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I'll try it when I get home and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: I hope it works the way you want it to! You may also want to set the bounds of the layerDrawable itself if it doesn't draw as intended

Comment: where at in the class should I put the 1st pice of code you suggested? thanks in advance :)

Comment: i get this error when I try your code:  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable so after so research I tried the code in the edited description and now no circle shows up please let me know your thoughts :)

Comment: you should load the R.drawable.iconbackbg during init(), and create a new LayerDrawable every time you set a new Icon. I don't know what you did to get the ClassCastException though.. you may have assigned the 'icon' to a LayerDrawable.